# Cloud Flare And Nodejs with python

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, npm, cloudflare

I have the following very simple few lines of code to scrape a cloud-flare and java script enabled website. But i am getting the following error.

Missing Node.js runtime. Node is required. Please read the cfscrape README's Dependencies section: https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape#dependencies.

As described in the documentation i have all of the following installed on my Windows based machine.

Dependencies

Python 2.6 - 3.x,

Requests >= 2.0,

PyExecJS,

Node.js is required for (safe) Javascript execution.

import cfscrape

import execjs

import npm

import nodejs

from scrapy import *

from lxml import etree

import sys

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

reload(sys)

sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

scraper = cfscrape.CloudflareScraper()

print scraper.get("http://www.sample.co.uk/").content

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have solved my problem by installing node.js from the following link.https://nodejs.org/en/ (in python folder). Thanks for someone posting comments on the following forum .https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3vgh5a/problem_with_execjs/